# Tensorflow checkpoints are being overwritten

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm training a model (a generative adversarial network) over an input-set using Tensorflow, and I would like to save model's parameters every 50 epochs.

Let say that I want to train the model for 1000 epochs, and save the model's parameters every 50 epoch, which would end up having 20 different checkpoint files.

By having a Session, and a Saver object, I simply use the following code to do so.

```
if num_epoch % 50 == 0:
    saver.save(sess=sess, path='RGAN-1/sv/' + type_exp, global_step=num_epoch)
```

The problem is, that checkpoints are getting overwritten, and at the end of the experiment, I only have the last 6 checkpoints, while I should have 20 checkpoints.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow checkpoint models getting deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018454/tensorflow-checkpoint-models-getting-deleted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.train.Saver` has a `max_to_keep` argument that is set to 5 by default. You can pass 0 to keep all checkpoints:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(..., max_to_keep=0)
```

See [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) for a full argument list.

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you very much.